# How to delete a folder that has 65535 links on it?

Tags: macos, symlink

Somehow a folder from `/var/folders` (`/var/folders/2j/8_50ggln3wz21k4gmfx86drh0000gn/T/` on my machine) got 65535 links to it. This caused my machine to not boot anymore.
I managed to fix the booting issue my renaming it to something else (`mv T X`) in recovery mode.

The problem is I can't get rid of it (`rm -rf` or even `ls` on it hangs).

```
ls -tahl ~/.Trash
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+    67 <user>  staff   2.1K Nov 30 00:30 ..
drwxr-x---  65535 <user>  staff   139M Nov 29 22:14 X
drwx------      3 <user>  staff    96B Nov 29 22:01 .
```

And if I try:

```
rm -r ~/.Trash/X
...(hanged, does not return)
```

Comment: Are you giving it enough time when it “hangs”?  How are you determining that it’s “hung” vs “just taking a really long time”?

Comment: I let it run for 1 hour+. the folder has only 139MB. Also, empty trash takes a long while and does not do anything

Comment: Please don't crosspost to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1272973/how-can-i-delete-a-folder-with-65535-links

Comment: Managed to remove the folder. I've used verbose mode and saw the progress

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  I suggest  trying the following:

```
cd ~
sudo find ./.Trash/X -delete
```

If that stalls out, then try:

```
cd ~
sudo rm -rf ./.Trash/X/*
sudo rm -f ./.Trash/X/*
sudo rm -rf ./.Trash/X
```

If that triptych also fails, then I would like to see the output of

```
sudo stat -x ./.Trash/X
```

Hope that this helps,

F.